# LINQ to Entities - using include with navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, include, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ query:

```
return ClientContext.Services.Include("Location").Include("Service1").Where(s => s.FkLocationId == currentLocation);
```

My Service class is as follows:

```js
 public partial class Service {
      public Service()
        {
            this.Service1 = new HashSet<Service>();
        }
   
     public virtual ICollection<Service> Service1 { get; set; }
public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
   }
```

With my LINQ Query, I expect to find the location of a given service, as well as its child services, both of which I can get correctly. But when I inspect inside the service objects inside the `ICollection<Service> Service1`, the location object is null.

Why don't I get the location navigation of the Service object in that collection?

What would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: You are eager loading related entities so don't need the virtual keyword on your navigation properties. Have you tried adding MultipleActiveResultSets=True to your connection string?

Comment: The service() class is actually the code generated from the EF.

Comment: Then you don't need the includes as EF should lazy load (which it isn't here :) Have you tested the service using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see whats going on?

Comment: lazyloading is disabled across the project. That's why I'm using the include

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to this is:

```
// This will load all Services, related Location and related Service1 and Location
ClientContext.Services.Include(m => m.Location).Include(m => m.Service1.Select(s => s.Location)).Where(s => s.FkLocationId == currentLocation);


// This will load all Services, related Location and related Service1 and Location using a string
ClientContext.Services.Include("Location").Include("Service1.Location")).Where(s => s.FkLocationId == currentLocation);
```

[More information about eager-loading and lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)